# Can EL&U please get its logo banner centered (again)?

Tags: feature-request, status-bydesign, design

The logo banner for English Language & Usage used to be centered. It was designed to be centered, way back when these things were created. How can I tell? Because it exhibits bilateral symmetry in a big way. The bar has matching bookend ornaments and a line motif extending from the ornaments to each side of the viewport. Even the typeface is all-caps, completing the symmetrical effect.

What we have now is not centered, and looks like a mistake:

[image: Uncentered banner]

What we should (at least) have:

[image: Centered banner]

You really ought to be able to see that centering is an improvement.

To make the change will be quite simple. You only need to replace one line of CSS, from `justify-content: space-between;` to `justify-content: center;`

```
.site-header .site-header--container {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 70px;
    max-width: 1264px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 8px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    /* justify content: space-between */
    justify-content: center;
    background-color: transparent;
    background-image: none;
    background-position: bottom right;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: auto;
}
```

Comment: It looks slightly better on a viewport of 1536px (1080p with 125% DPI) though...

Answer (score 5):

I'm sorry. This is something that I explained back in September on the site's announcement post regarding the updates. It's under [bullet point #1 in Mari-Lou's answer](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11694/121385).

> 1. Why is the web site's name pushed to the left?
>
>    Because all sites must have this placement moving forward. The goal of this update is to make the base LESS/CSS for the entire network as similar as possible, which requires that the logos all have the same positioning. Having these elements be the same makes it so that we can more easily roll out some of the feature requests that have been sitting around for years without risking breaking a chunk of the sites.

This means that things like site logos *must* be in the same position everywhere.

Comment: Then we need a new logo. This one clearly can't make the transition.

Comment: Upvoted because on EL&U this information was communicated early on. BUT It's easy to miss if you are only a sporadic visitor/user.

Comment: Then let's center all the logos....

Comment: @Mari-LouA: I got too depressed to follow all that. It's been like trying to convince Trump and the Republicans that climate change is real. You know they're just going to ignore everything you say, even if they pretend to listen.

Comment: @Robusto https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11888/we-tried-to-fix-it#comment51104_11894 If self-defeatism and apathy reign then nothing will ever be improved. You are EL&U's second highest rep user, use that position to make a difference! But you'll need to know *beforehand* what can or cannot be modified.

Comment: @Mari-LouA: What you rather insultingly call self-defeatism and apathy I see as practicality. Whatever my status may be on EL&U I am merely one set of eyeballs in the StackExchange network's desire to attract more of same while offering up less on the debit side of the equation. Have your meticulous efforts to document the stylistic transgressions here resulted in anything more than a band-aid applied to an amputation? My analogy about Trump and climate change at least recognizes the reality of the situation.

Comment: @Robusto hey, I wasn't insulting you or anyone in particular. Just saying that if everyone agrees that "There's nothing that can be done" nothing will be done. And you're absolutely right, my efforts haven't resolved anything except, perhaps, enlarging the logo... but if the results have been largely disappointing it's because "our" voice isn't strong enough. I can only moan about the theme on meta for so long, and then I have to admit defeat as well.