# New theme: fix serif-vs-sans font combinations

Tags: discussion, feature-request, design, theme-2018

In what I hope is the correct spirit of bringing concrete, actionable suggestions for changes and updates to the new theme, I would like to ask for the fonts to be harmonized as [tchrist went into great detail about here.](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11697/2490)  (tchrist covered it most excellently, I cannot hope to improve upon that explanation.)

Comment: Catija has said that since fonts are a cross-site design issue, it will take longer for them to be revisited.

Comment: On the one hand, because it is a bigger task, naturally it should take longer.  On the other hand, because it affects multiple sites and is very visible, it should be higher priority....